# php exec() command permission denied

Tags: php, linux, permissions, exec

I have a C++ executable file 'skypeforwarder'. skypeforwarder works if I use command line in Terminal in Mac:
  henry$ /Users/henry/Desktop/skypeForwarder/skypekit-sdk_sdk-4.1.2.20_793394/examples/cpp/tutorial/step3/skypeForwarder

```
sh: /Users/henry/Desktop/skypeForwarder/skypekit-sdk_sdk-4.1.2.20_793394/examples/cpp/tutorial/step3/skypeForwarder: Permission denied
```

But it always issued 'permission denied' if it is called in php exec();

```
<?php 
echo exec('whoami');

$output = null;

$execBuild = '/Users/henry/Desktop/skypeForwarder/skypekit-sdk_sdk-4.1.2.20_793394/examples/cpp/tutorial/step3/';
$execBuild .= 'skypeForwarder';

$n  = exec($execBuild, $output);
```

I searched a lot. The problem should be the problem of the php/browser permission in web server. I also tried to change the owner of the file from:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 henry  staff  1212716 19 Apr 11:23 skypeForwarder
```

to

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 _www  staff  1212716 19 Apr 11:23 skypeForwarder
```

It still does not work.

I set the apache in my mac according to http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/php_leopard.php

Comment: What's the output of exec("whoami");?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the file itself is readable by the web server, the `Desktop` folder most likely is not, and the web server therefore cannot traverse into it to locate the executable file.  You should move the `skypeforwarder`  binary file into a location readable by the web server, such as a directory parallel to where you are attempting to serve this PHP script.  That directory should not, however, be web-accessible. Protect it with .htaccess or place it above the web DocumentRoot, but it must be readable by the web server.

By default, `Desktop` on OSX is `-rwxr------` and it is *not* advisable to change permissions on that directory.

Moreover, it is very much *not* advisable to change the file to be owned and writable by `_www` the web server user.  Instead, it should be readable and executable by the web server, but not writable.

```
chown henry skypeforwarder
chmod 755 skypeforwarder
```

**Standard disclaimer:** As always, be extremely cautious when executing system calls from PHP scripts accessible on the web.

Comment: It was probably someone trolling because they were in a bad mood. I voted you back up.

Comment: It is working now. Permission denied because although I chown _www skypeforwarder, henry is still the owner of /Users/henry/Desktop/skypeForwarder/ directory. A colleague helped me to fixed the problem with 2 steps.       1. vi /private/etc/sudoers, add one line: _www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL                         2. chown _www:staff /Users/henry/Desktop/skypeForwarder/              Thanks Michael, many of your suggestions are right for me. I know it is not a good way to set the directory under /Users/henry/Desktop/. I will change that.

Answer (score 0):

Try look at the disable function in php.ini

```
disable_functions = exec
```

Comment: I searched in my /private/etc/php.ini, there is no disable_functions list. Thanks.

Comment: I see from your comment on the other post the the `exec("whoami")` has an output of _www which means that the function was allowed so it's not what I was suggesting. If it was disabled, you would get an error in the apache/PHP error log.