# How I get permission of exec function in PHP

Tags: php, exec

In my php server, I can not access exec function. How can I enable it and is it risk for my server?

Comment: This isn't the right place for this question. Contact the support people of your hosting service, but only after you read through the php docs on `exec` and `passthru` and the backtick operators thoroughly, because these functions, while sometimes useful, are to be avoided, especially when you're writing a web application. If you're talking about your local PHP installation, though: check the safe_mode ini settings

Comment: You could refer here [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236091/php-exec-command-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable it by disabling [`safe_mode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) in `php.ini`.

As far as whether or not you should do this for security reasons, I would say that it's a bit more secure to leave it disabled, but the risk should be minimal if you write your code in a safe manner and make sure to validate, sanitize, and properly-quote input. Using `exec()` with a constant argument tends to be fairly safe. But, doing something like `exec('myprogram ' . $_POST['user_id']);` is very very dangerous.

To safely pass an argument to `exec();`, you need to make use of [`escapeshellarg()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['user_id']))
{
    $userId = $_POST['user_id'];
}
else
{
    $userId = '0';
}

exec('myprogram ' . escapeshellarg($userId));
```